# alert shows entry updated succesfully but entry does'nt update in database

Tags: php

I am creating a updating form page. it shows no error but there is no updation in my database. 
I already check whole the database row names but that doesnt help.
that code is a little bit long but please help.

```
   <?php
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $update_id = $_GET['edit_form'];
    $bill = $_POST['b_no'];
    $naam = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile_no = $_POST['mobile'];
    $addres = $_POST['add'];
    $detail = $_POST['p_detail'];

    $p_img_name = $_FILES['p_img']['name'];
    $p_img_type = $_FILES['p_img']['type'];
    $p_img_size = $_FILES['p_img']['size'];
    $p_img_tmp = $_FILES['p_img']['tmp_name'];

    $prc = $_POST['price'];
    $deposite = $_POST['d_amt'];
    $remaning = $_POST['r_amt'];

    $b_img_name = $_FILES['b_img']['name'];
    $b_img_type = $_FILES['b_img']['type'];
    $b_img_size = $_FILES['b_img']['size'];
    $b_img_tmp = $_FILES['b_img']['tmp_name'];

    $p_date = date('y-m-d');

    move_uploaded_file($p_img_tmp, "images/Product/$p_img_name");
    move_uploaded_file($b_img_tmp, "images/Bill/$b_img_name");

    $update_query = "UPDATE new_entry SET bill_no='$bill', name='$naam', 
    mobile_no='$mobile_no', address='$addres', product_detail='detail', 
    product_image='$p_img_name', price='$prc', deposite_amt='deposite', 
    remaining='$remaning', bill_image='$b_img_name',Product_date='$p_date' 
    WHERE s_no='$update_id' ";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $update_query)) {

        echo "<script> alert('Entry Updated Successfully') </script>";
        echo "<script> window.open('view_entry.php','_self') </script>";
                } else {
                    echo "cant Update Entry.." .mysqli_error($conn);
                }

  } 

  ?>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: is `Product_date` correct? All other column names are entirely lower case.

Comment: yes i checked its correct

Comment: is `$update_id` `string ` or `int`

Comment: $update_id is  int  @UsmanRana

Comment: @MohitSoni Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES);` inside the if block at the beginning.

Comment: Is it will be helpful @Progman

Comment: i am still in trouble.!!

Comment: @MohitSoni As I said, please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES);`